# Creating hangman game without arrays

Tags: java, string

This is what the output should look like.

[image]

i need to find the index of guess in the original String.

If that's true than it should replace the question mark at the index with the char read in 
the string guess.

After that it should take out that char from the string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

If originalString doesn't contain guess than it should only take out that char from the string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

I looked up this question on Google and found a bunch of codes, they were all using arrays or something i have not learned in the class es. So please don't use arrays.

I am stuck at the if else statement.

```
    int count=1;
    while (count<=24){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int length;
        String originalString;
        String guess;
        String option= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String questionmarks;

        System.out.println("Please enter a string");
        originalString=keyboard.nextLine();

        length=originalString.length();

        questionmarks = originalString.replaceAll(".", "?");



        System.out.println("Original String: "+originalString);
        System.out.println("Guessed String: "+questionmarks);
        System.out.println("Characters to choose from: "+option);
        System.out.println("Please guess a character");
        guess=keyboard.nextLine();

        if (originalString.contains(guess)){
            count++;


        }


        else{
            option.replace(guess, "_");
            count++;
            System.out.println(option);

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things that I noticed from a cursory glance:

- `.replace()` returns a `String`, it will not modify `option` unless you do:

  `option = option.replace(guess, "_");`
- Also, since you don't want to use Arrays, I highly suggest that you use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

**EDIT 1 (based off of comment from duplicate thread):**
You can use a `StringBuilder` to have a String that's initialized to all `-`.  Then when someone guess a correct letter, you can replace the `-` with the `guess`.

```
StringBuilder sb_word = new StringBuilder(lengthOfOriginalString); 

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
     sb_word.append('-'); //add hyphens to StringBuilder, StringBuffer would also work
```

You should really use something like:

```
final char blank = '-';
```

Then, after someone makes a `guess`, if you've determined that the character at position `i` should be replaced by `guess`, you could do:

```
 sb_word.setCharAt(i, guess.charAt(0));
```

**EDIT 2**:

```
while (bodyparts > 0 && !win) //play game while you have bodyparts and haven't won
{       
     System.out.printf("Word to guess: %s\nEnter a letter or word guess: " , sb_word);
     guess = keyboard.next();

     if (guess.length() == 1)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) //loop to see if guess is in originalString
             if (Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(i)) == 
                 Character.toLowerCase(guess.charAt(0)))
             {  //it is, so set boolean contains to be true and replace blank with guess
                sb_word.setCharAt(i, guess.charAt(0));
                contains = true;
             }

        if (!contains)
        {
            bodyparts--;
            System.out.printf("Incorrect, you have %d bodyparts left.\n", bodyparts);
        } 
        else if (sb_word.indexOf(String.valueOf(blank)) == -1)
        { //all the letters have been uncovered, you win
            win = true;
            System.out.println(word);
        }
        else
        {
           contains = false;
           System.out.println("Good guess.");
        }
    }

    else
    {
        if (guess.equals(word))
            win = true;
        else
       {
            bodyparts = 0;
            System.out.printf("Incorrect, you have %d bodyparts left.\n" , bodyparts);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: _if you've determined that the character at position `i`_ -- i think this is what he is looking for :-)

Comment: Oh, this is good, I forgot about `StringBuilder` and just went with the ol' "rebuild a temp String with +=" approach. I like this better, though it sounds like OP may not be up to the `StringBuilder` part of his class yet.

Comment: yeah haven't leaerned stringbuilder either.

Comment: @Treasure I very, very rarely do this, but you seem very lost.  You have to take the initiative and learn for yourself.  Who cares that you haven't learned `StringBuilder`, go learn it.  Google, bro. Don't expect someone to just give you the code.  Not everything is explicitly there, ie variable declarations and such.  I'll leave that up to you to figure out, but the logic is correct.  Good luck.

Comment: @Treasure PS: If you copy this code and hand it in as your assignment: (a) your teacher or TA or what have you will most likely know that it's not yours, (b) it's simply plagiarism and (c) don't bother doing something stupid like simply changing variable names, it's not as clever as one may think (been a TA for the past 5 years, catch people cheating all the time).  Good luck.

Comment: no i am not gonna do that, i don't even completely understand your code yet.

Comment: and yeah obviously my teacher will know that i didn't do this since half the stuff you did is taught by him. Anyways appreciate you guys helping me.

Comment: @Treasure Added some comments in the code.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT2: cut all this, but basically, when you learn arrays, this will be so much easier.

EDIT: unrelated to the problem, but don't the conditions in your `else` block need to occur regardless of whether the guess was successful or not? You increment the count in both instances, and you'll need to blank out the guessed character whether it existed or not, correct?

PSUEDOCODE for inside the "successful guess":

```
String temporaryGuess = "";
for-loop for each character in originalString {
    if (character at current index = guess) 
        append guess to temporaryGuess;
    else
        append a ? to temporaryGuess;
}
set the previous guessed String to the temporaryGuess String
```

Comment: don't know what look-up is, yeah my guess is that we are suppos eto do it with array. Our professor isn't doing a good job of teaching. :S

Comment: Not to worry, you have the vast expanses of the Internet at your disposal. By "look-up" I simply meant you'd have to the `String.contains(char)` method, then find each index by looping through and calling `String.indexOf(char, lastIndex)` in order to find each instance of the character.

This is somewhat dry, but informative: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Not sure what you mean by taht method. How will i find the index number of that char guessed in the string?
Something like this?  originalString.indexOf(guess, lastIndex);

Comment: Well, I wrote a quick and dirty copy of your implementation and it turns out it is possible, but not as effecient as using Arrays. I'm not going to give you the exact code, but I'll post some psuedocode in my original answer.

Comment: and contain method doesn't accept char, it only accpets strings or am i wrong?

Comment: ok i will wait for that

Comment: The `contains` method does work on Strings only, yes, however anything inside a double quote, even a single character like "t", is treated as a String object of length 1.

Comment: alright i have this code. Not sure is this is what you want me to do.
System.out.println("Please guess a character");
guess=keyboard.nextLine();
char a= guess.charAt(0);
if (originalString.contains("a")){
 count++;
 System.out.println("You guessed correct.");
 for (int index = originalString.indexOf(guess);
       index >= 0;
       index = originalString.indexOf(guess, index + 1))
  {
      System.out.println(index);
  }
}

Comment: Not quite, though it is a fair starting point. You shouldn't modify `guess` because, as a String, its OK. Your loop should start at the beginning of `originalString` and loop through its entire `length`. For every character it loops through, it should compare that character's value to the character that the user guessed. If the guess is the same, it should append `guess` to `temporaryGuess`, else it should append `?`. After the loop, set the old `questionmarks` to `temporaryGuess`, as that is now the accurate representation of the remaining phrase.

Comment: not sure what you mean. Don't know what append method does either. My professor should really taught more material before giving this question.

Comment: I agree, he should have. Unfortunately, there's an unwritten (it may be written, I just haven't seen it) rule on this site not to give out exact code solutions for questions like this, and instead provide nudges in the right direction. You should have everything you need here, and if not, Google is your best friend. Search "appending to String" if you're unsure on that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on it, a playable Hangman game without arrays:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hangman {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);    
    private static String word;
    private static String availableChoices = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private static String hiddenWord;
    private static boolean winner = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter a word to guess: ");

        word = scanner.nextLine();
        hiddenWord = wordToQuestionMarks(word);

        System.out.println("Hangman Word Set: " + word + "\n\n");

        while (!winner) {
            guessLetter();
        }

        System.out.println("Congrats! You Win!");
    }

    private static String wordToQuestionMarks(String word) {
        return word.replaceAll(".", "?");
    }

    private static void guessLetter() {
        System.out.println("Hidden Word: " + hiddenWord);
        System.out.println("Characters to choose from: " + availableChoices);
        System.out.print("Guess a letter: ");
        String letterChoice = scanner.nextLine();

        int found = 0;

        if (hasLetter(letterChoice)) {
            found = updateGameState(letterChoice);
        }

        updateAvailableChoices(letterChoice);

        System.out.println("You found " + found + " " + letterChoice + "\n");
        gameOver();
    }

    private static int updateGameState(String letter) {
        int found = 0;

        for(int i=0; i< word.length(); i++) {
            if (word.charAt(i) == letter.charAt(0)) {
                String prev = hiddenWord.substring(0,i).concat(letter);
                hiddenWord = prev.concat(hiddenWord.substring(i+1));
                found++;
            }
        }

        return found;
    }

    private static void updateAvailableChoices(String removeLetter) {
        availableChoices = availableChoices.replace(removeLetter, " ");
    }

    private static void gameOver() {
        if (!hiddenWord.contains("?")) {
            winner = true;
        }
    }

    private static boolean hasLetter(String letter) {
        if (word.contains(letter)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Example Output

```
Enter a word to guess: stack
Hangman Word Set: stack


Hidden Word: ?????
Characters to choose from: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Guess a letter: a
You found 1 a

Hidden Word: ??a??
Characters to choose from:  bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Guess a letter: z
You found 0 z

Hidden Word: ??a??
Characters to choose from:  bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy 
Guess a letter: s
You found 1 s

Hidden Word: s?a??
Characters to choose from:  bcdefghijklmnopqr tuvwxy 
Guess a letter: t
You found 1 t

Hidden Word: sta??
Characters to choose from:  bcdefghijklmnopqr  uvwxy 
Guess a letter: k
You found 1 k

Hidden Word: sta?k
Characters to choose from:  bcdefghij lmnopqr  uvwxy 
Guess a letter: c
You found 1 c

Congrats! You Win!
```

Like others have said here, this is not the ideal way of doing this. Arrays would make this much cleaner.

Comment: If he doesn't know how to do this assignment, he almost definitely does not know how to use/write methods.

Comment: Kind of figured that, but I did this more for my own boredom.

Comment: Fair enough, I do that sometimes, too.

Comment: PS: you don't need `replaceAll()`, you can just use `replace()`.  `replaceAll()` is only needed when dealing with regular expressions.

Comment: yeah I am not gonna do this question. Just gonna ask my professor for help when i see him next class. Thanks for helping though.