# Making a hangman game

Tags: java, arrays, string

**Logic:**
This is how the output should look like. http://prntscr.com/1is9ht i need to find the index of guess in the orginalString. If that's true then it should replace the question mark at the index with the character read in the string guess. After that it should take out that char from the string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".

If originalString doesn't contain guess than it should only take out that char from the string "**abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz**" I looked up this question on google and found a bunch of codes, they were all using arrays or something that I have not learned in the classes. So please don't use arrays. I am stuck at the if else statement. Is there any way to solve this problem without using Arrays.

```
int count=1;
while (count<=24){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int length;
    String originalString;
    String guess;
    String option= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String questionmarks;

    System.out.println("Please enter a string");
    originalString=keyboard.nextLine();

    length=originalString.length();

    questionmarks = originalString.replaceAll(".", "?");



    System.out.println("Original String: "+originalString);
    System.out.println("Guessed String: "+questionmarks);
    System.out.println("Characters to choose from: "+option);
    System.out.println("Please guess a character");
    guess=keyboard.nextLine();

    if (originalString.contains(guess)){
        count++;


    }


    else{
        option.replace(guess, "_");
        count++;
        System.out.println(option);

    }
```

Please suggest me some code that doesn't implement array concept for my problem,
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you made no progress since you first asked [21 mnutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998138/creating-hangman-game-without-arrays)? Didn't the answer you got help you? Why?

Comment: @assylias is there a way to mark questions as duplicates?

Comment: @Deactivator2 Since you don't have enough reputation yet, you can't vote to close, but you can flag it.

Comment: No one answered until i posted this, than deactivator answered in my other question right when i posted this

Comment: @Treasure: You don't need to re-ask things. especially not 20 minutes apart.

Answer (score 0):

A few things that I noticed from a cursory glance:

- `.replace()` returns a `String`, it will not modify `option` unless you do:

  `option = option.replace(guess, "_");`
- Also, since you don't want to use Arrays, I highly suggest that you use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

**EDIT 1 (based off of comment from duplicate thread):**
You can use a `StringBuilder` to have a String that's initialized to all `-`.  Then when someone guess a correct letter, you can replace the `-` with the `guess`.

```
StringBuilder sb_word = new StringBuilder(lengthOfOriginalString); 

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
     sb_word.append('-'); //add hyphens to StringBuilder, StringBuffer would also work
```

You should really use something like:

```
final char blank = '-';
```

Then, after someone makes a `guess`, if you've determined that the character at position `i` should be replaced by `guess`, you could do:

```
 sb_word.setCharAt(i, guess.charAt(0));
```

**EDIT 2**:

```
while (bodyparts > 0 && !win) //play game while you have bodyparts and haven't won
{       
     System.out.printf("Word to guess: %s\nEnter a letter or word guess: " , sb_word);
     guess = keyboard.next();

     if (guess.length() == 1)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) //loop to see if guess is in originalString
             if (Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(i)) == 
                 Character.toLowerCase(guess.charAt(0)))
             {  //it is, so set boolean contains to be true and replace blank with guess
                sb_word.setCharAt(i, guess.charAt(0));
                contains = true;
             }

        if (!contains)
        {
            bodyparts--;
            System.out.printf("Incorrect, you have %d bodyparts left.\n", bodyparts);
        } 
        else if (sb_word.indexOf(String.valueOf(blank)) == -1)
        { //all the letters have been uncovered, you win
            win = true;
            System.out.println(word);
        }
        else
        {
           contains = false;
           System.out.println("Good guess.");
        }
    }

    else
    {
        if (guess.equals(word))
            win = true;
        else
       {
            bodyparts = 0;
            System.out.printf("Incorrect, you have %d bodyparts left.\n" , bodyparts);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: option = option.replace(guess, "_");
we have not learned stringbuilder either.
So now my code works if the char guessed is wrong. Any advice on what to do if they guess the right character?

Comment: @Treasure I very, very rarely do this, but you seem very lost.  You have to take the initiative and learn for yourself.  Who cares that you haven't learned `StringBuilder`, go learn it.  Google, bro. Don't expect someone to just give you the code.  Not everything is explicitly there, ie variable declarations and such.  I'll leave that up to you to figure out, but the logic is correct.  Good luck.

Comment: @Treasure PS: If you copy this code and hand it in as your assignment: (a) your teacher or TA or what have you will most likely know that it's not yours, (b) it's simply plagiarism and (c) don't bother doing something stupid like simply changing variable names, it's not as clever as one may think (been a TA for the past 5 years, catch people cheating all the time).  Good luck.